# What's wrong with this sql

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I want to update fields in a table `'my_table'`, but it reports:

```
ProgrammingError: (1064, 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; ...
```

PS: `values` is a list of strings and `len(values) == len(fields)`
Expression of *sql* is:
 `'update my_table set field_a=\\'%s\\',field_b=\\'%s\\',field_c=\\'%s\\',field_d=\\'%s\\''`
Because `len(fields)` may change when running the program, I use the following codes:

```
field_str = ''
for field in fields:
    field_str += (field + "='%s',")
field_str = field_str[: -1]
sql = "update %s set %s" % (my_table, field_str)
values = [current_response_dict[site][info_type] for site in site_list for info_type in self.all_info_type]
cursor.execute(sql, values)
conn.commit()
```

Comment: Show the value of `sql` before you try to execute it. Do some basic debugging.

Comment: @Jeroen Vannevel I've added the value of sql generated in debug mode.

Comment: 'update my_table set field_a=\\'%s\\',field_b=\\'%s\\',field_c=\\'%s\\',field_d=\\'%s\\''

Comment: @BhargavRao I remove '\\' by change the expression to :field_str += (field + "='%s',"), still dosen't work.

Comment: Have you tried running that in its raw format in SQL?

Comment: @DrSchizo Thanks for your suggestion and how to turn it into raw format? any documents? I'm quite new in python, especailly in mysql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `'` are unnecessary. And you have a update without `where`-clause?

```
sql = "update %s set %s" % (my_table, ','.join('%s=%%s' % f for f in fields))
values = [current_response_dict[site][info_type] for site in site_list for info_type in self.all_info_type]
cursor.execute(sql, values)
```

Comment: Only one record hence no need for where clause. I'll try your answer.

Comment: For simplity of expression, I temporly set: values = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'] and it reports: query = query % tuple([db.literal(item) for item in args])
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string